# Quotes behavior in UTF-8

Tags: character-encoding, html-entities

I am working on a HTML5 website, using UTF-8 charset.

I tried to use the (double curly quotes) **“”** directly on my page, but they are not appearing as they should and showing a weird character instead. I changed my browser's character encoding to Western (ISO-8859-1) and the quotes started showing.

I thought this was supported in UTF-8 Charset? or am i wrong?

The HTML Entities on the other hand are working perfectly, “ and ”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the symptoms, it seems that the actual encoding of your HTML document is not UTF-8 but windows-1252 (not ISO-8859-1, which does not contain curly quotes at all—but most browsers actually use window-1252 when told to use ISO-8859-1).

This depends on the way you have saved your HTML document. It is normally an option in an editor or other authoring tool to set the encoding.

Comment: thanks, that seem to have been the case. I was using “Komodo IDE” editor and it sets the encoding of the file itself by default to Western European (CP-1252), i switched that to UTF-8 over there too and the “double curly quotes” started working. It seems it was conflicting, with what the page can handle and what the page is requesting to handle?, To be honest, i didn't know that made a difference and i was never sure what difference that made - but i do now, lol.